# Why UILabel in UINavigation is not centered

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I use custom back btn in navigation controller:

```
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                             initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", nil)
                                             style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                             target:nil
                                             action:nil];
    //and add custom label in this:
    heightNav = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height;
    widthNav  = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.width;
    self.aCNavLabel = [[ACNavLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, widthNav, heightNav)];
    self.aCNavLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Settings", nil);
    //
    UIView *titleNavView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, widthNav, heightNav)];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleNavView;
    [self.navigationItem.titleView addSubview:self.aCNavLabel];
```

but label is not centered.
**Please tell me where I made a mistake?**

and custom label aCNavLabel:
    @implementation ACNavLabel

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
   self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
   if (self) {

      self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      self.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
      self.font = FONT_OP_STD(22.0f);
 //   self.text = title;
      self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    }
    return self;
}
```

I change some rules for this 
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.aCNavLabel;
and and there was something incredible
[image]

this is first viewController and
[image]

and next what is this????

Comment: Set textaligment to center as well.

Comment: i use custom label and in init method use self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

Comment: set by change self.navigationItem.title

Comment: simply add self.navigationItem.titleView = self.aCNavLabel;

Comment: Can you post an image of what your navigation bar looks like

Comment: http://d.pr/i/tLgt this is looks like

Comment: if i use `self.navigationItem.titleView = self.aCNavLabel;` http://d.pr/i/N3xr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:(NSDictionary *)
```

This method will be Ok
you can customer the navigationBar title about the font,the color,the textAlign and other properties;

Comment: thank you, this is what is needed. [this tutorial is help](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-navigation-status-bar-ios-7/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text alignment to center like:

```
aCNavLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Refer the [UILabel textAlignment property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/textAlignment) for more options.

or as @NANNAV suggested use:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.aCNavLabel;
```

Comment: i use custom label and in init method use self.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter

Comment: is not center look it d.pr/i/N3xr

Comment: @user3116236: Now I got the issue, the issue is happening due to the back button. You need to set the label width as (navItemwirth - backbuttonWidth)

Answer (score 0):

```
self.aCNavLabel = [[ACNavLabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, widthNav, heightNav)];
self.aCNavLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Settings", nil);
self.aCNavLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; // SET THIS
```

Answer (score 0):

```
aCNavLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

try it.

Answer (score 0):

Create category for UINavigationBar and programmatically adjust the position of your title label. set ACNavLabel view as titleview.

UINavigationBar+MyNavigationBar.h

```
@interface UINavigationBar (MyNavigationBar)

@end
```

UINavigationBar+MyNavigationBar.m

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (MYNavigationBar)

- (void)layoutSubviews {

for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {

    if ([view isKindOfClass:[ACNavLabel class]]) {

            view.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x, self.center.y);

    }

 }

}

 @end
```